How to display the number of students when there are no arguments
So basically i have an exercise where i have to show the numbers of students in a file students.csv with a city as an argument that goes like
cat students.csv | ./ex_02.sh ncy
and it should show me the number of students that are in ncy
Which i did.The problem is that when i have to execute the script with no arguments i  just have to show the total number of students.That's where i have an error.
#!/bin/bash
if \[! "$1"\]
then
  cat students.csv | wc -l
else
  cat students.csv | grep -i $1 | wc -l
fi

then i get an error when i have no arguments,when i do have one i get the number of students with the arguments

We can't see your CSV.

what do you think \[! "$1"\] means?

@MarkSetchell the csv is not relevant - this is just a bash syntax mistake

@jhnc The CSV is required both for a [mcve] and also to avoid semantic mistakes.

with grep -i ncy you're searching for ncy in all the fields of the CSV, so what happens if a student is called Rancy, hm?

This  one-liner should produce the same output as the code in the question (after fixes): grep -ci -- "${1-^}" students.csv

@pjh "a null BRE shall match every line" - so even just grep -ci -- "$1" students.csv

The text on the bash tag popup instructs people to test their code with shellcheck. In this case, shellcheck does not find the error.
The bash if keyword should be followed by a command to run. The exit value of the command determines which branch is subsequently taken.
The code in the question specifies that the command is \[! (expands to the word [!) and that that command should be passed a single argument "$1"\] (expands to a word containing the expansion of $1 followed by a close bracket character).
It seems you have no command named [! on your system. So trying to run it fails and the else branch is always executed.

It is likely that you intended to use the [ (aka test) command.
It would be given as:
if [ ! "$1" ]
# ...

Note the separation of the command [ and each of its arguments - the whitespace is not optional.
Because the else branch is executed even when $1 is not set, the grep command will give a usage error since grep -i is not valid. If you had quoted $1 (ie. grep -i "$1") it would have masked the if failure since the empty string matches any line.
